# Convert float/int to Calendar in jpa hibernate SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I'm developing a Java project with JPA / Hibernate and SQL Server DB.

I got an existent db where date fields are stored as int and datetime as float.

Does anyone know how can I implement a transparent conversion to a Calendar type in my domain class?

I must calculate the date in getter and setter or there's a better way?

Thank you!
Marco

Comment: what do the integers mean? Is 1100 11am or is that 1100 seconds after 1970 or 1100 ms after 1970. more infor please

Comment: Do you mean you have two different columns that represent date and time and those should be merged to a single `Date` class in the domain object? Could you give an example of how the date and time are stored?

Comment: In Sql Server executing: 

select cast(0 as datetime) -> 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
select cast(41148 as datetime) -> 2012-08-29 00:00:00.000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it as follows:

1. Two classes, MyDate & MyDateTime each implementing the Hibernate [`UserType`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html) interface.
2. MyDate will read the integer date as String, assuming the integer is of the format 20120828. In the `nullSafeGet()` implementation, it will convert this string to a Joda DateTime or `Java.util.Date` using the `SimpleDateFormat` class with format as "yyyyMMdd".
3. MyDateTime will read the `float` as `String`, assuming the `float` is of the format 20120828.190800. In the `nullSafeGet()` implementation, it too will convert this string to a Joda Datetime or `java.util.Date` using the `SimpleDateFormat` class with format as "yyyyMMdd.HHmmss".
4. The `nullSafeSet()` will format back the data using the same `SimpleDateFormat` in the respective classes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution! Hope is useful for someone!

As suggested by Vikdor I've implemented UserType interface:

```
public class MyDate implements UserType{

    private final static int SECONDS_IN_A_DAY = 86400;

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable)value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        return ObjectUtils.equals(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
         assert (x != null);
         return x.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        assert names.length == 1;

        final String value = (String) StringType.INSTANCE.get(resultSet, names[0]);
        if (value == null) return null;     
        try{
        final String daysValue = value.substring(0, value.indexOf("."));
            final String secondsValue = value.substring(value.indexOf("."));

            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1900);
            calendar.setTime(DateUtils.truncate(calendar, Calendar.YEAR).getTime());

            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, Integer.valueOf(daysValue));
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, (int)(SECONDS_IN_A_DAY * Float.valueOf(secondsValue)));
            return calendar;
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new HibernateException("Cannot convert DB value " +value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * Convert from date to float
     */
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object value, int index) throws HibernateException, SQLException {     
        final Calendar currentDate = (Calendar) value;
        final Calendar zeroDate = Calendar.getInstance();

        zeroDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1900);
        zeroDate.setTime(DateUtils.truncate(zeroDate, Calendar.YEAR).getTime());

        final Days days = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(zeroDate), new DateTime(currentDate) );

        final Seconds seconds = Seconds.secondsBetween(new DateTime(DateUtils.truncate(currentDate, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH).getTime()), new DateTime(currentDate) );
        float finalValue = days.getDays() + ((float)seconds.getSeconds()/SECONDS_IN_A_DAY);

        preparedStatement.setFloat(index, finalValue);      
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Calendar> returnedClass() {
        return Calendar.class;
    }

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[]{
                FloatType.INSTANCE.sqlType()
        };
    }

}
```