# Cast field in JPA Query

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jpa

In my sql-server, the field DATE are saved in float format (es: `DATADOC = 42155`)

I want to import the field in mysql DB as DATETIME.
I try on sql-server to cast the field with this query:

```
SELECT CAST(DATDOC as DATETIME) -2 FROM FATTURE where id=25460;
```

And the result is correct.

Now, I want to translate it in JPA Query:

```
TypedQuery<DateTime> convFattura = emI24.createQuery(" SELECT CAST(dataFattura as DATETIME) -2 FROM FatturaI24 f where f.id = :idFattura", DateTime.class);
```

But I obtained this error:

```
    09-06-2015 14:32:00 ERROR: org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.CastFunction.render(CastFunction.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.SqlGenerator.endFunctionTemplate(SqlGenerator.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.methodCall(SqlGeneratorBase.java:2326)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.simpleExpr(SqlGeneratorBase.java:2681)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.expr(SqlGeneratorBase.java:1476)
```

What is the correct syntax of the CAST in DATETIME?

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `'-2'`? Are you trying to subtract 2 days? months? or ????

Comment: @RavinderReddy Days, in this way I obtained the correct traslate (I have verified this)

Comment: CAST is not valid JPQL. You could use the SQL function "CAST" using JPQL standard "FUNCTION" (in JPA 2.1)

Comment: Try to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160303/convert-float-int-to-calendar-in-jpa-hibernate-sql-server

Comment: There is NO SUCH THING AS JPA 2.5. If you mean ECLIPSELINK v2.5 then that is a VENDOR EXTENSION

Comment: In the native Query we do like this : 


`SELECT CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS varchar) COLUMN_NAME FROM TABLENAME`

If you test the cast like that it gives you what?

So in my case i casted all my fields as varchar and in my java code i cast them to the right format whitch i want , because it gives me an exception like that , i don't remember of the right erros message exactly but some think like that

Comment: @TinyOS I try to do it but I obtained an error of IllegalStateException.

Comment: Can you debug and te me when it gives you this exactly ? and during the debug you can inspect and get the right query whitch writen

Comment: @TinyOS Is Syntattically incorrect.`TypedQuery<String> convFattura = emI24.createQuery(" SELECT  CAST (dataFattura as VARCHAR) FROM FatturaI24 f where f.id = :idFattura", String.class);`

Comment: using JPA and native SQL queries at the same time is ... really pointless - doesnt make any sense. JPA only makes sense if you want to make your database algorithms **database-vendor independent** *(also : less error-prone, much more portable and stable)* ... which you're pretty much negating with non-JPQL queries. Oh and : you're not actually using JPA ... you're passing queries through your EntityManager. JPA = database entity objects and criteria

Answer (score 0):

As you said in the comment , the return value is a float type so what we will do is not doing a cast in sql but convert the float with java code and you have bellow the right code :

```
Query convFattura = emI24.createQuery(" SELECT f.dataFattura FROM FatturaI24 f where f.id = :idFattura");
            convFattura = convFattura.setParameter("idFattura", idFatturaValue);  
        float dataFattura = convFattura.getSingleResult();
```

---

java code to convert float to date :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (int) dataFattura);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, (int) ((dataFattura * 60) % 60));
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, (int) ((dataFattura * 3600) % 3600));

DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat();
fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris")); 
System.out.println(fmt.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Hope that is useful for you !

Comment: Excuse me, but my problem isn't this. I want to convert a float value in DATETIME. The query to extract all value run, but the dataFattura value is (p.e: 42155) and this value is inusable for me.

Comment: I modified my answer can you check it and tel me if that resolves you issue

Comment: I had used this way but don't run. The result is incorrect (es:dataFloat = 42171, DateFormat =  07/04/20 5.00 ) In my first query the resultSet start to year 2012. It's a mistery :)

Comment: can you use this structure in your query : `convert(datetime,convert(varchar(20),convert(int,convert(float,<feild name)))) `

this is an example:

`SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,Col1) AS DATETIME) AS NewValue FROM TABLE1`

Answer (score 0):

try to use Convert function instead of Cast function.
it works for me ...!

Comment: You could improve your answer adding references and explaining the differences between the two methods and why would one work and not the other.